# How to use ng-click to load an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, api

I am a beginner with angularjs. I am also utilizing ResponsiveVoice.JS for the voice component of the app. My issue is that if I use ng-click, the voice doesn't work. If I use onClick, it works. How do I use this API with ng-click?

I need it with ng-click because I need to pass in the voice text as a parameter from my routeParams in the controller.

**Here is the image that will play the voiceover when clicked.**

`<img src="images/audio.png" onclick='responsiveVoice.speak("Text spoken.", "UK English Male")'  class="pull-right"/>`

**Here is the link to the api that I have loaded into my index.html in the head section.**

`<script src='http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>`

**What I want it to be is like this**

`<img src="images/audio.png" ng-click='responsiveVoice.speak({{ parameter from controller }}, "UK English Male")'  class="pull-right"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`responsivevoice` is a global object but `ng-click` only recognizes methods or expressions that are available via angular scope.

A global object however can be accessed from any javascript in the page.

Thus the simplest way you can do it is to create a scope object that references the global object:

```
$scope.responsiveVoice = responsiveVoice;
```

Now you can use `responsiveVoice` in the view

To use parameters from scope create a slightly different version

```
$scope.speak = function( item){
   // i have no idea what objects are used...assuming it has property `text`
   responsiveVoice.speak(item.text,  "UK English Male");
}
```

Then html would be

```
<img src="images/audio.png" ng-click="speak( scopeObject)">
```

Comment: note update to use it with passing a scope variable in view

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img src="images/audio.png" ng-click='responsiveVoice.speak("{{ parameter from controller }}", "UK English Male")' class="pull-right"/>
```

You might have been passing a string from controller. Which is making your function call as

```
responsiveVoice.speak(param, "lang")
```

This will break you function call, as function is expecting a string parameter